# How do I connect to an xterm process and perform IO?

Tags: linux, process, xterm

I have an xterm running a long task on a Linux machine. I want to log in and connect to that xterm and see what is going on ... (I trying to explain this as best as I can).

I guess what I am asking is - Can I Monitor and Control an xterm that is already open on the desktop WHEN I log in remotely? Is there a way to pipe IO in and out of it?

Comment: The easy way is to use `tmux` or `screen` _before_ you need to do this. :)

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: http://pasky.or.cz/dev/retty/